# Clock wise and anti clock wise rotation of matrix in java

Tags: java, oop, matrix, rotation

Question
Write a java program to rotate a matrix n times in clockwise and anti clockwise direction using inheritance
1.Create a base class clock
2.From this extends a child class clockwise and anticlockwise
3.Both of these child classes should contain the method rotate().

This is the code I wrote for clockwise and anti clock wise rotation of matrix in java, I am confident that logic for the code is correct but anticlock wise rotation is not working properly can someone help me with this

```
import java.util.*;

class Clock {
}

class Clockwise extends Clock {
    int[][] mat1;
    int m, n, r;

    Clockwise(int m, int n, int r, int[][] mat1input) {
        this.m = m;
        this.n = n;
        this.r = r;
        this.mat1 = mat1input;
    }

    void rotation() {
        while (r > 0) {
            mat1 = rotate(m, n, mat1);
            r -= 1;
        }
        System.out.println("Clockwise");
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                System.out.print(mat1[i][j] + " ");
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }

    int[][] rotate(int m, int n, int mat[][]) {
        int row = 0, col = 0;
        int prev, curr;
        while (row < m && col < n) {

            if (row + 1 == m || col + 1 == n)
                break;
            prev = mat[row + 1][col];
            for (int i = col; i < n; i++) {
                curr = mat[row][i];
                mat[row][i] = prev;
                prev = curr;
            }
            row++;
            for (int i = row; i < m; i++) {
                curr = mat[i][n - 1];
                mat[i][n - 1] = prev;
                prev = curr;
            }
            n--;
            if (row < m) {
                for (int i = n - 1; i >= col; i--) {
                    curr = mat[m - 1][i];
                    mat[m - 1][i] = prev;
                    prev = curr;
                }
            }
            m--;
            if (col < n) {
                for (int i = m - 1; i >= row; i--) {
                    curr = mat[i][col];
                    mat[i][col] = prev;
                    prev = curr;
                }
            }
            col++;
        }
        return mat;
    }
}

class Anticlockwise extends Clock {
    int[][] mat2;
    int r;
    int top, left;
    int bottom, right;
    int prev, curr;

    Anticlockwise(int[][] mat2input, int r) {
        mat2 = mat2input;
        this.r = r;
    }

    void rotation() {
        mat2 = rotate();
        System.out.println("Anti clockwise");
        for (int i = 0; i < mat2.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mat2.length; j++)
                System.out.print(mat2[i][j] + " ");
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }

    int[][] rotate() {
        for (int z = 0; z < r; z++) {
            top = 0;
            left = 0;
            this.bottom = mat2.length - 1;
            this.right = mat2[0].length - 1;
            while (left < right && top < bottom) {
                prev = mat2[top + 1][right];
                for (int i = right; i > left - 1; i--) {
                    curr = mat2[top][i];
                    mat2[top][i] = prev;
                    prev = curr;
                }
                top += 1;
                for (int i = top; i < bottom + 1; i++) {
                    curr = mat2[i][left];
                    mat2[i][left] = prev;
                    prev = curr;
                }
                left += 1;
                for (int i = left; i < right + 1; i++) {
                    curr = mat2[bottom][i];
                    mat2[bottom][i] = prev;
                    prev = curr;
                }
                bottom -= 1;
                for (int i = bottom; i > top - 1; i--) {
                    curr = mat2[i][right];
                    mat2[i][right] = prev;
                    prev = curr;
                }
                right -= 1;
            }
        }
        return mat2;
    }
}

public class MatrixRotation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int m = sc.nextInt();
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int[][] matrix1 = new int[m][n];
        int[][] matrix2 = new int[m][n];
        sc.nextLine();
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                String[] line = sc.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
                for (int j = 0; j < line.length; j++) {
                    matrix1[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(line[j]);
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        int r = sc.nextInt();
        sc.close();
        System.arraycopy(matrix1, 0, matrix2, 0, matrix1.length);
        Clockwise clockwise = new Clockwise(m, n, r, matrix1);
        Anticlockwise anticlockwise = new Anticlockwise(matrix2, r);
        clockwise.rotation();
        anticlockwise.rotation();
        // System.out.println("Anti clockwise");
        // for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        // for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        // System.out.print(res2[i][j] + " ");
        // System.out.print("\n");
        // }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

according to me i guess when you are copying the matrix so both the matrix are pointing to same memory location that is why when you are computing clockwise the matrix2 also change with matrix1 and anticlockwise is computing on the final value after clockwise
so you can use basic for loop instead of System.copy() method.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Anticlockwise anticlockwise = new Anticlockwise(matrix2, r+r);**
Use the above statement to get your required output